# How to Ignore Single double quotes in csv Hive table like Hello"World

Tags: csv, apache-spark, hadoop, hive

I am using serde class with `escapeChar='\"'` but the value is stored as
NULL instead of Hello World/

```
>> cat file.csv 1, Hello"World

>> table ddl

create table test (id int, name string) ROW FORMAT SERDE              
| |   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'     | | WITH
SERDEPROPERTIES (                             | |  
'separatorChar'=','
    'escapeChar'='\"'
    'quoteChar'='\"')                             | | STORED AS INPUTFORMAT                              | |  
'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'       | | OUTPUTFORMAT     
| |   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat' |

>> Output:
Hive: Select * from test; 
ok 
1, NULL
```

????

Comment: Why do you need escapeChar or quoteChar? What other data is in your input file that requires those?

Comment: Issue might be that your quoteChar and escapeChar are same. Try using a different quoteChar and escapeChar for this particular data.

Comment: I am using quote char because the except the above column for all the other column data was enclosed by(") Like "Apache,Hadoop"            EscapeChar- is for escaping (")